# Probability and Markov chains in a knight's tour

Tags: probability, matrices, discrete-mathematics, markov-chains, chessboard

I've been working on my math IA for a month now,  but I cannot happen to stumble across anything important to calculate within my chosen topic. I've tried optimization of algorithms but it went wrong, as well as graph theory. I've been developing this new attempt by using matrices in order to get the long term probability of being in a given square of the 4x3 chessboard, but I cannot calculate the steady-state probability for the matrix. I'd appreciate any help or even another ideas in order to carry on with the project.  [This is the previous matrix I was talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0hAs.png). Every state is a tile in which the knight can be placed, and the probability in the content of the matrix is the probability of landing in that square from the previous one.

Comment: The entries in each column add to 1, but I don't see any relation for the rows. It would seem if the entries were the probabilities for a knight to be at various positions in the grid, then the total of all should be 1, rather than only column totals sum to 1. You need to explain better what your matrix means, and what you hope to do with such matrices.

Comment: @coffeemath I get your point. My  matrix has two axis, the one with the current states and the  one with the possible states. If we look at it vertically,  we see that the possibilities add up to 1, as when you only have 2 possible movements, each one has 1/2 chance of happening at random. But when we look at it horizontally, things change, as you can get to the same state but  from different  origins, which, depending on  their possible individual moves, will not add up to 1. Hope that clarifies  your doubt. I appreciate your interest btw.

Comment: @coffeemath do they have to add up to 1 on both ways?

Comment: D Paz: I looked again and your matrix makes good sense, since you have put all the current knight positions along the top row, and then entries give probabilities to jump from current position to some other position labelled by the side pairs. So it is indeed only the vertical columns that should add to 1. Note that in a usual Markov transition matrix the start positions are along the side

Comment: I noticed that on a 4X3 board a knight can in enough moves get from any square to any other. Note in a usual matrix for a Markov process, the "from" states go along the left of the matrix with the "to" states across the top. This only means take the transpose of your matrix. There are standard methods to obtain long term probabilities of being in each state, given a specific starting state. so that is computable but you may need software... I'm not up on such packages.

Comment: I think you can compress your state set using the symmetry of the 4x3 board the knight moves on. The four corners will have the same likelihoods. the top middle and bottom middle also the same. The four edge pieces not in top or bottom row are the same. And the two centers of second and third rows the same. Then your transition matrix will be 4x4 instead of the original 12x12 which would make it possible to do calculations by hand.

Comment: @coffeemath So you are saying that I should compress those squares that have the same probabilities or that resemble each other  due to symmetry  into a single element on the matrix? It is really smart. I'll give it a try then. I really  appreciate the help!!

Comment: Yes that is exactly it. Let me know what you get for final probabilities to be in each of the four types and we could compare. I suggest also that you include your work in the questio0n, as it already has  close votes.

Comment: When I wrote before I used the phrase "depending on the initial state". However in your situation the general theory is that long range probabilities to be in the various states does *not* depend on the initial state. There will be a definite probability to be in each state.

Comment: @coffeemath I was thinking on calculating the limit of the matrix when it is multiplied by itself infinitely many times, in order to see how the different tiles of the chessboard end up looking like, but I've got no idea on how to do it. Do you know anything about it? I was thinking on making the matrix smaller, like dividing it into little pieces because it is impossible to do it by hand on a 12x12 matrix, but that leads into Jordan normal form, which looks really difficult. I appreciate it!

Comment: You should use the 4x4 matrix M discussed before, based on symmetry of thre initial 4x3 chessboard. Be sure to make it with "from" states on left side and "to" states across top. Then you need to find a 1x4 row vector v whose entries are positive and sum to 1, and satisfies vM=v.